# How to add a UIButton on top viewForHeaderInSection

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

How to add a button on top off viewForHeaderInSection. I like to add a button above section header which can be scrollable with tableview. Any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

The - rather hackish - solution I saw in a pull-to-refresh implementation is to simply add your 'extra' view to the table view as a subview - just make sure it's positionned using a negative y offset. That offset should be equal to (well, rather -1 times) the height of your view. Code:

```
UIView *myViewAboveHeader = // however you create it
CGRect f = myViewAboveHeader.frame;
f.origin.y = -1 * f.size.height;
myViewAboveHeader.frame = f;
[tableView addSubview:myViewAboveHeader];
```

Edit: it seems you don't want a header view AND a view above it. In this case, just simply add a button on top of the view you return in your table view delegate method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)s
{
    UIView *header = ...;
    UIButton *btn = // create a button somehow;
    [header addSubview:btn];
    return header;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make only UITableView visible when use enter into the view. And if he scroll down then show that button ? Like the search bar on the contact native application.

Comment: @AmitVyawahare that's what I suggested in the first part of my answer (before the edit).

Answer (score 1):

Use this code, placing it in `viewdidload`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIView *headerViews = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 90)];

    UIButton *managePrivacyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [managePrivacyButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45, 320, 45)];
    managePrivacyButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    [managePrivacyButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    [managePrivacyButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [headerViews addSubview:managePrivacyButton];
    [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:headerViews];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make only UITableView visible when use enter into the view. And if he scroll down then show that button ? Like the search bar on the contact native application.

Answer (score 0):

This method in particular takes as a return an UIView. UIButton is a subclass of UIView. Just create a new UIButton and return it.

Comment: But problem is i need header as well as button.

Comment: so, create an UIView, add a label as a subview to assign the header text, and add the UIButton as a subview of that view.